# EAP issue on Exchange 2016

Tags: exchange-2016

Today I deployed exchange 2016 based on Windows server 2012 R2 in my home lab environment. Everything was fine but when I try to create email address policy, I got following error. Then, I searched on microsoft technet forum but I didn't get solution.And I also tried to create EAP both on chrome and firefox.

[image: EAP Issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Exchange 2016 do you use?

Did you try the IE on the server side? Try to open the ECP on the server side and login as admin account.

In addition, you could also try the Exchange Management Shell: “New-EmailAddressPolicy”.

Here is [a related case](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/77bf63d5-0c90-46eb-b030-ed3455da07fa/cant-add-eap-no-information-floods-in-from-email-address-format?forum=exchangesvradmin).